# How to deny access to server while allow user to access if they edit etc/hosts

Tags: linux

There is something i hope somebody can help me,
After research for a long time, I really dont know how do some server capable to deny all access from visitors but we can only access that server if we define some value in etc/hosts
Example :
ip adrdress.   Hostname
xxx-xxx-xxx  www.example.com

Please can somebody how to achieve something like that?

Comment: `/etc/hosts` isn't a security mechanism. This is a serious [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to block all access from the outsider, but only allow direct access if the user define the server's alias in the etc/hosts file. Is there any way to achieve something like that? Thank you!

Comment: You're repeating yourself. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer 
https://coderwall.com/p/yz-2_a/limit-ssh-access-by-ip-address

```
sshd : localhost : allow
sshd : 192.168.0. : allow
sshd : 99.151.250.7 : allow
sshd : mydomain.net : allow
sshd : ALL : deny
```